# Regular Expressions _# at end of string

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I am using the [REGEXP_LIKE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501) function in Oracle 10g to find values in a column with a suffix of _#(like _1, _2 etc). I can find _# in any part of the value with the query below but can I return only values with _# at the end ?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN,'_[[:digit:]]')
```

Comment: If you find yourself getting stuck on things like this, you might try googling for a regular expressions cheat sheet. You'll have to make sure you get one that matches your particular flavor, but then it's very easy to scan a single page for "$  End of line".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure.  Use...

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN,'_[[:digit:]]$')
```

The `$` character matches "the end of the string."

Comment: THANKS !! I though I was going to have to spend some quality time with my "Mastering Regular Expressions" book. Still on the to-do list but for another day.

Comment: You really really really ought to read that book.  Understanding regex is a major contribution to coder productivity.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use reg exps.

```
select * from table where substr(column,-2) between '_0' and '_9';
```